# Installing PyFTGL: distribution not found

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, ftgl

I am trying to install PyFTGL, to display text in my OpenGL project.

I usually install libraries using pip, but

```
sudo pip3 install PyFTGL
```

returns the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyFTGL (from versions:)
No matching distribution found for PyFTGL
```

I also tried easy_install after reading [this wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyftgl/wikis/HowToBuild.wiki), but

```
sudo easy_install PyFTGL
```

returns the following error:

```
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('PyFTGL')
```

What am I doing wrong ?

I am using python3.6 on my Macbook OSX Yosemite.

---

EDIT: after installing dependencies (FTGL, freetype, and boost-python) I still seem to miss a library. 
I get the following error message when running the `python setup.py install` command from the source code directory:

```
ld: library not found for -lGLU
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang++' failed with exit status 1
```

Although I can already do this in python: `from OpenGL.GLU import *`

Comment: before trying `sudo easy_install PyFTGL` didi you download the source code, extracted it and `cd` into the directory where the `setup.py` lies?

Comment: Yes I did. 
But I just noticed that other libraries (FTGL, FreeType, boost::python) are required before attempting to build PyFTGL. I will try installing these first, and edit my question if my problem has changed.

Comment: after installing the dependencies, try running the `python setup.py install` command from the source code directory